# GroupBy by each month

Tags: laravel

I'm studying GroupBy I can display year around result using below code.

How do I display each month by `'created_at'` column data?

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $branches = DB::table('contacts')
        ->select('branch','created_at')
        ->orderBy('created_at')
        ->groupBy(DB::raw(MONTH('created_at')))
        ->get();

    $ttl_c = Contact::count('id');

    return view('index', [
        'branches' => $branches,
        'ttl_c' => $ttl_c,
    ]);
 }
```

index.blade.php:

```
<table border="0">
@foreach($branches as $branches => $branch)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $branch->branch }}</td>
    <td>{{ $branch->branch_count }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: Can you add info on what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Abishek sorry I can't think of so I asked here. and thank you for link I will take a look.

Comment: @Abishek I looked the page what your tought me. and I changed code like this but I'm not sure how to adjust. and current I got Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\MONTH() error. Could you teach me correct code please?

Comment: $branches = DB::table('contacts')
        ->select('branch','created_at')
        ->orderBy('created_at')
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'))
        ->get();

Comment: Dear @John Lobo Thank you very much. You again! I tried your code and I got Undefined property: stdClass::$branch_count . I would like to display 2021 June , 2021 July etc... Could you teach me blade file also ?